# Как привязать к bottom элемент new Bottom Navigation bar в navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

Создал изначально шаблон navigation drawer,данный шаблон создал автоматчиески разметку( [image: введите сюда описание изображения]).
Вообщем, пытаюсь использовать BottomNavigationView ,добавил в основную разметку activity_main.xml, запускаю приложение и меню по середине,а должно быть привязано к  Bottom.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"


        app:itemBackground="@color/navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationview" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Контент: **content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"

            android:text="@string/fion"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fiontext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint=" "
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text=""

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fionuri"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

            android:text="@string/adrespropiski"/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/naselpun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/naselpunkt"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/naspunkt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint=" "
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text=""/>

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/adres_ul"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/adres"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ulica"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint=" "
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="2"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
            android:text=""/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phonetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/dom"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="30"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/email"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailfild"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLength="20"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mesag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/star_512"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:text="@string/messag"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mesages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="введите ваше сообщение"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="1000"
            android:maxLines="5"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:
с разметкой:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        app:itemBackground="@color/navigation"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationview" />
</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эмм... `android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"`.

Comment: первая разметка это что? как она относится ко второй?

Comment: @xkor
я же указал,что создал шаблон navigation drawer который автоматом создал разметку под контент и под виджеты.
первая разметка: activity_main

Comment: ну я у вас в разметках никакого navigation drawer и в помине не вижу и на скриншоте какая то каша ничем не напоминающая боковое меню

Comment: у вас приведен лишь кусок activity_main.xml, и по нему ничего определенного сказать нельзя

Comment: @ xkor
хм,посмотрите еще раз, я привел полный код из xml

Answer (score 1):

Привет. У тебя это все в CoordinatorLayout лежит? если нет, то во первых оберни весь layout в CoordinatorLayout. И попробуй выставить  для BottomNavigationView android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Answer (score 0):

У вас `BottomNavigationView` лежит напрямую в `DrawerLayout` который ничего не знает об атрибуте `layout_alignParentBottom`. Собственно этот атрибут работает только в RelativeLayout. В `DrawerLayout` же надо как вам уже предложили в другом ответе использовать `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`, но я не уверен на сколько полная у `DrawerLayout` поддержка атрибута `layout_gravity`. Кроме того у вас `BottomNavigationView` описан после `NavigationView` и соответственно будет отображаться поверх бокового меню когда оно открыто. Я бы рекомендовал вам изменить activity_main.xml так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/navigation"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
            app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationview" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Обновил шапку и прикрепил результат с вашей арзметкой

Comment: @upward очень странно, попробовал создать пустой проект с аналогичной разметкой и нижний бар вполне себе внизу: https://monosnap.com/file/NYFfSucHfG4keu8CZdoMhhXrRormbD . У меня правда сейчас не последние версии сдк. Вечерком после работы попробую с последними.

Comment: @upward эх, чтот у меня вообще с 25ми сдк и сапорт либами не захотело заводиться никак(